# Как в HTML увеличить размер checkbox?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. В HTML, checkbox имеет некий стандартный размер (именно область, где ставится крестик или там птичка). Мне надо его увеличить. Например, на 20 пикселей. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нельзя сделать. Не рекомендую использовать height, width и padding - это даст непредсказуемый эффект в разных браузерах. Можно заменить чекбокс другим элементом (лучше ссылкой, т.к. на нее можно переводить фокус), и стилизовать уже его. У самого чекбокса вместо type="checkbox" сделать type="hidden", и менять value по клику на заменяющую чекбокс ссылку с помощью JavaScript.

Comment: Блин, как сложно. Но все равно, спасибо.

Comment: Да ничего сложного там нет, ссылку можно стилизовать двумя картинками, 1- до клика, 2- я после клика(флажок установлен), можно ещё конечно для наведения 2, но это уже заморочка. При этом ты получишь уникальные поля checkbox.

Comment: Да у меня задача просто была сделать программно генерируемый HTML-код на основе некоего xml-файла, который является чем-то вроде бланка. Т.е. то, что здесь предлагается - легко, но в моем случае - тяжелее.

Answer (score 0):

Отличный, легковесный плагин jQuery для стилизации html-элементов типа checkbox. Очень прост и в тоже время эффективен: [jquery-checkbox](http://wdtime.ru/jquery/jquery-checkbox). Может кому пригодится.